# Open source C# vt100 server

Tags: c#, terminal-emulator, vt100

Does anyone know of an open source C# vt100 server? I'm looking to create a C# server that understands the escape sequences from a vt100 client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a C# one but this [Java one](http://www.koders.com/java/fidF61659C4E58388E01A64C8C151F972588EB58221.aspx?s=FileItem) has the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

This takes me waaaay back.  I... don't think it's the server, but the application, that needs to understand the escape sequences.

The server only needs to pass them to the application that's running.

Think of a text-based application.  It needs to know what the user is sending to it so that it can send back the proper response.  The terminal server you're talking about sits between the application and the user, acting as part of the communication layer.  What the server can (and should) do is send a request for terminal type and parse the result to make sure it's talking to a VT100.  But, beyond that (even logging in is another application), I'd leave it to the application to respond to commands coming down the wire.

Another way to look at it: imagine the server is up and running.  What will it dump a user to?  The C:\?  That's telnet.  What good would a VT100 escape sequence do at a DOS prompt?  Not a lot (a DOS prompt is really "command.com" talking back to the user - the "application" I was talking about earlier; telnet isn't interpreting the escape sequences, it's simply passing them to command.com and command.com spits out the response).

Comment: In my case I want to write the application that responds to the client rather than just passing the commands through to a console or shell process. Coding what response to send back when the delete, insert, up, down, arbitrary control keys are received from the client is what I'm seeking to avoid.

Comment: So the, "server," is really the, "application."  The VT100 command set isn't  huge.  Unlike current technology, you actually have a pretty small, fixed and easy response set and, wonder of wonders, it behaves the same way on different devices!  (take THAT HTML!)    I'd think you could use that .Net generic server sample out there.  Then store the Esc sequences and their responses in XML (XPath could do all the heavy lifting of providing responses).  Is it going to be serial or IP via a hardware terminal server? Remember: software VT100s aren't 100% the same as beautiful hardware VT100s.

Answer (score 0):

If you have vt100 client, you should create simple tcplistener and setting it to listen 23 port. Send vt100 commands . If you want, I can send c# code

Comment: Really, after 6 years you need to necro this?

Answer (score -1):

Hve u tried [ackterm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ackterm/)?...I've just googled the term "vt100 implementation .net" (after u've responded to my [ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643594/c-transform-a-string-targeted-for-the-unix-shell-use-for-the-windows-command-pr/1643700#1643700)) and I got an article on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/terminalcontrol.aspx) which talks about ackterm. I think you'd want something close...it is a telnet client (I think) which understands how to parse vt100 commands. This is my observation. (I've used it to connect to my telnet server). Its open source and hence you'd have to figure out what part of the code you need. I just discovered about it today, and still in the process of extracting what I need. I know its in there somewhere...

Hope this helps. I owe u a thanx for mentioning to me its a vt100 stuff.