# c#: transform a string targeted for the unix shell use for the windows command prompt

Tags: c#, windows, unix, transform, command-prompt

Here is a sample string I got off a socket stream.

```
\033[H\033[J\033[1;30HSUPERVISOR MAIN MENU\033[6;5H 0.  Exit         Exit\033[7;5H 1.  Help         Display help\033[8;5H 2.  Control      Calling lists and users\033[9;5H 3.  Campaign     Campaigns\033[10;5H 4.  Manage
```

If you want to see the output I expect open a unix/linux shell, type **echo -e** followed by a space followed by the above string in single quotes and hit Enter key. The output appears something like:

```
                     SUPERVISOR MAIN MENU


 0.  Exit         Exit
 1.  Help         Display help
 2.  Control      Calling lists and users
 3.  Campaign     Campaigns
 4.  Manage
```

I want the same output except it should be in memory...I require to work with it later...any ideas.

Comment: just curious... whose socket stream? and why were you looking at it?

Comment: just opened a socket which connects to one of our unix boxes. We r just interested in the data we receive from it...based on whats there we want to issue commands...

Answer (score 1):

I asked an almost equivalent question a few hours ago: [Open Source C# VT100 Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641026/open-source-c-vt100-server).  You want a client library that understands the vt100 escape commands.

I searched around for a while and to date haven't found any very good vt100 C# libraries. I've gotten started on a custom one and since I really only need to interpret left and right arrows and backspace it hasn't taken long.

Luckily the vt100 standard is very promiscuous and not overly complex. I don't think it would take you very long to whip up some code to understand the escape commands in your example. This link has a nice concise list of the [VT100 escape sequences](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/dataformats/ascii/) (you need to scroll down a bit). Another good site is [vt100.net](http://vt100.net.).

In your example the escape sequences are being in octal. Your first escape sequence is:

```
\033[H
```

which translates to the ASCII below and is used to set the cursor position.

```
ESC [ H
```

The second one is

```
\033[J
```

which translates to the ASCII sequence below and means clear the line to the end of screen.

```
ESC [ J
```